# Filesystem in Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I tried to follow the guide from this site http://culttt.com/2015/10/26/generating-pdfs-from-html-and-phantomjs where you can generate PDFs using PhantomJS.

However, the authors code includes creating a PDFWriter class, that in its constructor accepts `Filesystem $storage`.

So when I want to use this class to generate a PDF, I', not sure what to feed the writer with?

```
$pdf = new PDFWriter( /* ?? */ );
$pdf->write('template.file', ['data']);
```

Any clues? I was supposed to implement this on a Laravel 4.2 installation.

Answer (score 0):

The author is injecting `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem` using the new Laravel 5 contract. You can resolve the same instance by using the `app()` method in Laravel 4:

```
$filesystem = app('Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem');

$pdf = new PDFWriter($filesystem);
```

Though if you're using this method inside a controller I'd suggest inserting it into your constructor.

```
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    protected $filesystem;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     */
    public function __construct(Filesystem $filesystem)
    {
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $pdf = new PDFWriter($this->filesystem);
        $pdf->write('template.file', ['data']);
    }
}
```